# Spring JPA - Export to csv based on table records

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, opencsv

I'm quite new here, but as I could not find the answer myself. I was hoping someone might.

I am using springboot with jpa to connect to a PostGreSQL db. From this i am retrieving a table e.g exportconfig containing a list of tables that need to be exported to CSV, and it also specifies which columns to export. I decided to use OpenCSV-BeanToCSV For this.

As I am using the spring boot jpa, i am not sure how to generate the query based on the ExportConfig table: e.g i would like to create a query like this:
"Select ... FROM :Tablename" where tablename is based on the value i retrieve from the exportconfig table.

I would appreciate if anyone has any recommendations on how to approach this, any alternative methods are always welcome.

Comment: Perhaps i should add I am using the JpaRepository

Comment: If you have something to add, you can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41765720/edit) to add it.

Comment: If I'm reading this right, it looks like it's just a matter of building your query string, then supplying it to `createQuery(String)` on the `EntityManager` instance that should already exist.

Comment: You are correct with the interpretation of building the query string, dynamically namely based on the records retrieved from the exportconfig table. However with spring boot starter jpa, EntityManager is no longer used. But perhaps i can still use it for this , Thanks I will look into that.